# Can anyone provide me pseudocode of IPL ZCO 2014?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, data-structures

Here is the link: https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO14004.
I am able to do it recursively through code:

```
  ans=answer(array[],0,0,0);
  function answer(tokens[], j, ans,n){
if(n==0||i>=tokens.length){
return 0;
   }
int k=ans+=tokens[i];
if(max<(k)){
    max=k;
}

ans(tokens,i+1,ans,n-1);
ans(tokens,i+2,ans,2);

return max;
}
```

But this takes huge amount of time for large inputs. Please tell me where should i memoise the code.Thanks

Comment: Ehm, java is not the same as javascript. What you posted is Javascript code. I took the liberty to change the tags on your question.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The code is gibberish - not Java nor Javascript, and full of syntax errors anyways.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, a linear approach can be implemented in a very simple way. 
For each game, we have three possible best-case earnings:

- With two more games which may be played
- With one more games which may be played
- With a mandatory pause

So it suffices to keep track of these three variables and just process the loop one with simple math operations.

```js
var input = [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3];

var sum2 = 0; // best case with two more games allowed
var sum1 = 0; // best case with one more game allowed
var sum0 = 0; // best case with no more game allowed

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var best = Math.max(sum0, sum1, sum2);
  sum0 = sum1 + input[i];
  sum1 = sum2 + input[i];
  sum2 = best;
}

document.write(Math.max(sum0, sum1, sum2));
```